# Problems with tabHost, buttons and vertical scrolls

Tags: android, button, scrollview, android-tabhost

I am doing an aplication and I need a tabhost with vertical scrollview in all the tabs, and one of them also need to have a button which bring us to another layout.

The thing is that all the tabwidgets are displayed properly but it doesn't work the scrolling in any of the tabs. And the button doesn´t work at all... I tried to debug and I checked that even the buttons's methon on onclick is never called when I press the button

I am desperate, I need a solution, I've already lost a lot of time here.

This is the most important part of the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/TabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


            <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Logic expression entered:"/>
                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textViewE2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Large Text"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Logic expression reduced:"/>
                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textViewD2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Large Text"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonD1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="See the esquematic"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the important code of the Java class

```
public class Traduccion extends Activity{
String estado_expresionlogica ="A*B*C+A*¬B*C";
TextView tvD2,tvE2;
String sfuncionreducida;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.traduccion);

    Resources res =getResources();
    TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost);


    //Tab 5
    tabs.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec5 =tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 5");
    spec5.setContent(R.id.tab5);
    spec5.setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm));

    //charging the textview needed 
    this.tvE2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewE2);

    tvE2.setText(estado_expresionlogica);


    //Tab 4
    tabs.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec4 =tabs.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
    spec4.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    spec4.setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm));

    //Cargar los textviews que sean necesarios para la pestaña
    this.tvD2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewD2);

    ////////Here is a code to copy the answer on sfuncionreducida 



    tvD2.setText(sfuncionreducida);

    tabs.addTab(spec5);

    tabs.addTab(spec4);         
}




public void Esquematico(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent (Traduccion.this, ReducidaEsquematico.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

I wish you can solve at least one of the two problems.. The one with the scrollview or the one  with the button!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use tabs with viewpager instead of using tabhost and scrollview

Comment: @dpsingh It sounds as I have to change everything, do you think that there aren't a way to solve it with tabhost?

Comment: So the idea is to implement it in good ways and there are libraries which can help you build the above stuff very easily then why to go wacky way.

Comment: @dpsingh What libraries? What is the API level required?

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator it has android minimum version support.

Comment: @dpsingh I did it with a view pager and I want now to get my shared preferences in one of the fragments! Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Yes, you can use getActivity().getSharedPrefrences() to get your prefrences.

Comment: @dpsingh I get it, but not that way! Thanks a lot for your idea! Using tabs with viewpager was a great idea for my app.